# How to display properties from a deserialized, nested JSON object in your view?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, object, jira

I made a model for accepting JSON data from the Jira API. I deserialize the JSON data using Newtonsoft.Json and save it in an object called jiraObj. If I put a breakpoint on the `return View(jiraObj)` line, I can see that my object is succesfully filled with information.

I'm not sure how to show information in my view. I've tried calling the controller class and the property names, but I can only seem to reach my upper level class in the model.

Here I collect information with the Jira API.
I call my class Jira to create an object to hold the expected information from my model.

```cs
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(accessToken));
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

            Jira jiraObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jira>(content);

            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View(jiraObj);
```

This is a snippet of the first few classes in my model file.

```cs
 public class Jira
    {
        public ICollection<Body> Issues { get; set; }    
    }

    public class Body
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Key { get; set; }

        public Fields Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        public Status Status { get; set; }
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        public string Summary { get; set; }
        public Assignee Assignee { get; set; }
        public Creator Creator { get; set; }
        public Reporter Reporter { get; set; }
    }
```

My model is very nested, I can only seem to access `public ICollection<Body> Issues { get; set; }`

I had no trouble accessing properties with just one class. I can't seem to figure it out after struggling for a few hours.

Edit: View code, tried many different iterations of the following

```
@model IEnumerable<TestJira.Models.Jira>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        @item.Summary
    </div>
}
```

Edit 2: The following code works.

```
@model TestJira.Models.Jira

@Model.Issues.ToList()
@foreach (var Issue in Model.Issues)
{
    <div>@Issue.Fields.Summary</div>
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in the view code.

Comment: Added it as an edit in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the model declaration in the view so it is not an enumerable, and use a for loop.:

```
@model TestJira.Models.Jira


    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Issues.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            Model.Issues[i].Summary
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)

I changed my Issues ICollection to a List, because i could not index it and with your code it now works :)

Comment: Actually, I changed it up a bit, and convert the ICollection to a list in my view. I also use a foreach loop to minimize errors. I added the code at the end of my question. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction